# php.ini - setting upload_tmp_dir

Tags: file-upload, php

I have a page which allows users to upload photos - fairly standard php I think.

This works on the live server I've been using to date but I've recently set up php on my Mac and now the uploads have stopped working.

I'm guessing this is because the the upload_tmp_dir is not set properly in the php.ini file.

Does anyone know what I need to do?

EDIT:

Here's the error message that's output...

`Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open 'upload/thumbs/AL.jpg' for writing: Permission denied in /Users/tom/Sites/tombrennand/add.php on line 128 Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open 'upload/images/AL.jpg' for writing: Permission denied in /Users/me/Sites/mysite/add.php on line 135 Notice: Undefined variable: con in /Users/me/Sites/mysite/add.php on line 172 Warning: mysql_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Users/me/Sites/mysite/add.php on line 172`

So from that I think I need to set permissions on that folder. Any ideas?

Comment: "I'm guessing this is because..." Do some debugging and check the error logs to find the cause.

Comment: Sounds like a plan... where do I find the error logs though??

Comment: +1 for the detailed error message. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open
>   'upload/thumbs/AL.jpg' for writing:
>   Permission denied in
>   /Users/tom/Sites/tombrennand/add.php
>   on line 128

You need to set the write permission on folder `upload/thumbs`

Since this is your personal computer, you can just `cd` into folder `upload` and then `chmod 777 thumbs` in Terminal.

Comment: absolutely... I tried that with dreamweaver but no joy. I guess I need to do it somewhere a bit more specialist.

Comment: Do an `ls -l` to verify. Also double check the `uploads` directory to ensure is enterable (executable bit).

Comment: I've tried `chmod 777 thumbs` but that returns `chmod: thumbs: No such file or directory`. Do I need to add the route to that directory? So something like `chmod 777 upload/thumbs`

Comment: chown root:www-data upload/thumbs ?

Answer (score 3):

Change the

```
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp/whatever
```

entry in your `php.ini` file. Ensure that this location is writable by the appropriate user/group.

Comment: You cannot change upload_tmp_dir at runtime. By the time a script runs, the upload process has already occurred.

Comment: a change in the .ini file is not "runtime" , you should add the chown to apache usually www-data , like chown root:www-data /newupload_dir/ and preferable the 755 permission.

Answer (score 0):

View your phpinfo in a new page to see what it is set to:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If it isn't where you need it to be, you can edit it with your php.ini file.

Comment: So if it isn't where it needs to be - how do I know where it needs to be? Are there any rules around this?

Comment: The location is arbitrary. As long as you can write to the directory you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I did a move_uploaded_file() to a folder I knew IIS users have writing permissions then I unzip that file.
By default my PHP.ini is using c:\windows\temp and even if I gave writing permissions to IIS users it wasn't working.

Comment: change it to c:\temp in php.ini and give 777 to the new folder