# Apache 1.3.37 server returnes 403 Access Denied when post request

Tags: php, apache, centos

#### update 2022-05-14

i found that server shows 403 when post request, not get request. get reqeust works well, not post.

---

hi i got problem with the apache server

that server started response `403 Access Denied` in unexpectedly when users access **some** files.
that files was working well before it. and other files in same directory can access well.

detailed error message is " You don't have permission to access "{FILE_PATH}/cart_write_exec.php" on this server."

i try to fix it with bunch of stackoverflow pages:

##### Directory Indexes: [Error message "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

`cart_write_exec.php` is specific php file. not directory. so i think it is useless

##### deny,allow directives: [Error message "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

that server's `httpd.conf` is already seted. and i didn't any modify to that file since 2012.

```
<Directory /home/*>
    AllowOverride All
    Options +ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

##### Require directive (Apache 2.4): [Error message "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

that server's apache version is 1.3.37

##### Files permissions: [Error message "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873295/error-message-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server)

`cart_write_exec.php` is already `777` and directory contained that file is `777` too.

```
drwxrwxrwx  4 image***   502   4096  5▒▒ 11 21:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 33 image***   502   4096  4▒▒ 24 18:33 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2 image*** users   4096  4▒▒  7 21:43 bak
-rwxrwxrwx  1 image*** users   3667  5▒▒ 11 21:18 cart_write_exec.php
drwxrwxrwx  3 image***   502   4096  4▒▒ 18  2012 img
-rwxrwxrwx  1 image*** users  20682  1▒▒ 24  2011 login_oo.html
-rwxrwxrwx  1 image*** users  20682  1▒▒ 24  2011 login_oo.php
-rwxrwxrwx  1 image***   502  20758  9▒▒ 29  2011 oo.html
-rwxrwxrwx  1 image*** users  10485  9▒▒ 28  2011 oo_list.html
-rwxrwxrwx  1 image*** users 100240  5▒▒ 11 21:32 pu.html
-rwxrwxrwx  1 image*** users  23934  4▒▒  7 21:37 pu.js
-rwxrwxrwx  1 image*** users  44927  4▒▒  7 22:44 pu_h.20220407.html
-rwxrwxrwx  1 image*** users  13741  4▒▒  7 22:45 pu_h.20220407.js
-rwxrwxrwx  1 image*** users  44440  4▒▒  7 22:44 pu_h.html
-rwxrwxrwx  1 image*** users   5593  4▒▒  7 22:45 pu_h.js
-rwxrwxrwx  1 image*** users   8949  4▒▒ 19  2012 web.html
-rwxrwxrwx  1 image*** users  45834  2▒▒ 17  2012 web4444.html
-rwxrwxrwx  1 image***   502   9936  7▒▒  3  2008 web4444444444.html
```

##### SELinux security context: https://www.happyjung.com/lecture/2481

i think selinux security context is not installed on my server.

cuz `ls -alZ` is shows nothing like below.

```
drwxrwxrwx  image*** users                                  bak
-rwxrwxrwx  image*** users                                  cart_write_exec.php
drwxrwxrwx  image***   502                                  img
-rwxrwxrwx  image*** users                                  login_oo.html
-rwxrwxrwx  image*** users                                  login_oo.php
-rwxrwxrwx  image***   502                                  oo.html
-rwxrwxrwx  image*** users                                  oo_list.html
-rwxrwxrwx  image*** users                                  pu.html
-rwxrwxrwx  image*** users                                  pu.js
-rwxrwxrwx  image*** users                                  pu_h.20220407.html
-rwxrwxrwx  image*** users                                  pu_h.20220407.js
-rwxrwxrwx  image*** users                                  pu_h.html
-rwxrwxrwx  image*** users                                  pu_h.js
-rwxrwxrwx  image*** users                                  web.html
-rwxrwxrwx  image*** users                                  web4444.html
-rwxrwxrwx  image***   502                                  web4444444444.html
```

but i try do the `chcon --type=httpd_sys_content_t cart_write_exec.php`. it returns error: `chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file cart_write_exec.php`

that server's apache version is 1.3.37, php version is 4.4.7, centos version is centos-release-5-1.0.el5.centos.1... whatever..

Comment: Security support for the 1.3 branch of Apache HTTPD ended 12 years ago! You aren't even running the latest patch! Upgrade to 2.4.

Comment: Those permissions are terrible for a production environment. 755 folders and 644 files. Then check file and folder owners, the owner should match the owner of apache. Something like www or www-data as the owner. Uploading a file over ftp and upload in a php/html form will set different owners, fyi

Comment: @MisterG13 well. i changed a permission of files and directory that contain the file to 755 and 644. but it doesn't help. that server still can't `access cart_write_exec.php`. i checked the ownership of httpd. it was root. so i changed ownership of `cart_write_exec.php` to `root`. but it doesn't help. i wish someone shot my head. then i can tell him to my client 'oh sorry, your server is dead, and i'm dead too.'. anyway, Thank you very much of your comment

Comment: @Quentin yeah. i know it. i didn't expected i can see the apache server that under version 2. but i saw it. and it kicked me up. anyway. actualy that is not my server. MY CLIENT'S server. but i call it mine. cuz i have some pronoun problem.

Comment: Try checking php's temporary upload directory... https://stackoverflow.com/a/6034073/19070801

Comment: @MisterG13 i checked it up. it shows nothing. owner is root, apache owner is root, too. and permission is 777.

Comment: if it is empty, change to '/tmp' (linux) like the link describes. do not use the root user. PHP, apache and the destination folder show all have the same owner, usually 'www-data'. if needed create the user. you can use https://superuser.com/questions/91935/how-to-recursively-chmod-all-directories-except-files to fix all permissions faster. also check php ini for file uploads ON https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433932/how-to-add-file-upload-in-php-ini#30433980

Comment: @MisterG13yes. actualy upload_tmp_dir show me /tmp. and if php fileupload is off it must shows php error, not apache error.

Comment: @MisterG13 i found it just shows 403 error on post request. not on get request.

Comment: Then the problem is in the code on the cart page. If Apache is several versions out of date, I imagine the code syntax is also. Try debugging the cart page, find the last line of successful code execution